# hyperref: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, luatex, dvips

```
hyperref: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',(hyperref)
because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}
```

How can i fix this error?

I m trying to compile a template of MMA journal. It is under this link [MMA Template](http://inga.vgtu.lt/~art/)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Class [`mma.cls`](http://inga.vgtu.lt/~art/k_abs_files_k_abs_f_file_bw.php?key=2813) is intended to be used with `latex`+`dvips` and contains several driver option settings:

```
\usepackage[dvips,a4paper,colorlinks,breaklinks,unicode]{hyperref}%backref,
\usepackage[dvips]{color}
```

If you want to use `pdflatex`, then remove options `dvips`.

Comment: it works but when i remove `dvips`, figures are not be shown in pdf file.

Comment: @SefaAnılSezer: The class uses `\usepackage{graphicx}` without options. In TeX Live and MiKTeX `graphics.cfg` of the distribution detects pdfTeX. Image types PNG, JPEG, PDF, JBIG2, MPS are supported. TeX Live also loads package `epstopdf` to support EPS images with automatic conversion to PDF.

Comment: But still I am getting the same error "hyperref: Wrong DVI mode driver option `dvips',(hyperref) because pdfTeX or LuaTeX is running in PDF mode. \ProcessKeyvalOptions{Hyp}"

Comment: @SudhirBelagali Have you removed the option `dvips` anywhere from the class file, the global and local options?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek , Thank U , I have just removed dvips from my class file ,, so it is working now , Thank U again